# Jackson xml deserialization - serialize to a list with arbitrary elements in between

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-parsing

I am using Jackson to deserialize XML. It works fine when serializing into a list when there are no other elements in between, but if i insert some other field in the middle somewhere, it seems to only put the things below the field into my list. See below only the ProductA objects after the Product B tag are being included.

I set a breakpoint to get the JsonNode object using the xmlMapper readTree method, and the properties above the ProductB tag are not there in the node tree.

Is there a way using jackson (or another library) to get all ProductA elements inside the Warehouse element, independent of the ordering of the Warehouse child elements?

```
public class Warehouse {
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ProductA")
private List<ProductA> productAList;

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ProductB")
private String productB;
//getters and setters

}
```

```
public class ProductA {
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "PropA")
private String propA;

//getters and setters
}
```

```
<Warehouse>
 <ProductA>
  <propA>abc</propA>
 </ProductA>
 <ProductA>
  <propA>abc</propA>
 </ProductA>
 <ProductB>def</ProductB>
 <ProductA>
  <propA>abc</propA>
 </ProductA>
</Warehouse>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your Warehouse class to use a method just for setting the value of productAList from XML, and remove the annotations from the productAList property.

```
@JsonSetter(value =  "ProductA")
public void setProductAListFromXml(ProductA productA) {
    if (this.productAList == null) {
        this.productAList = new ArrayList<ProductA>();
    } 
    this.productAList.add(productA);
}
```

Here is the full Warehouse class:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Warehouse")
public class Warehouse {
    private List<ProductA> productAList;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ProductB")
    private String productB;

    public List<ProductA> getProductAList() {
        return productAList;
    }

    public void setProductAList(List<ProductA> productAList) {
        this.productAList = productAList;
    }

    @JsonSetter(value =  "ProductA")
    public void setProductAListFromXml(ProductA productA) {
        if (this.productAList == null) {
            this.productAList = new ArrayList<ProductA>();
        } 
        this.productAList.add(productA);
    }
    
    public String getProductB() {
        return productB;
    }
    
    public List<ProductA> getProductA() {
        return productAList;
    }
}
```

Using the class like this:

```
String str = "<Warehouse>\r\n" + 
                " <ProductA>\r\n" + 
                "  <propA>abc</propA>\r\n" + 
                " </ProductA>\r\n" + 
                " <ProductA>\r\n" + 
                "  <propA>abc</propA>\r\n" + 
                " </ProductA>\r\n" + 
                " <ProductB>def</ProductB>\r\n" + 
                " <ProductA>\r\n" + 
                "  <propA>abc</propA>\r\n" + 
                " </ProductA>\r\n" + 
                "</Warehouse>";
        
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
Warehouse warehouse = mapper.readValue(str, Warehouse.class);
System.out.println(warehouse.getProductB());
System.out.println(warehouse.getProductA());
```

Produces this output:

```
def
[ProductA [propA=abc], ProductA [propA=abc], ProductA [propA=abc]]
```

Comment: this worked for one of the fields, but strangely not for another. Say I have productC which is identical to productA in everything but the names, as a field of the warehouse class. It was deserializing all of productA elements but only 1 of 2 productC's. Anyways I was able to get what i needed using w3c/javax document parsing.